# The number of roots of the equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^3}-3x+\sin x$

Tags: calculus, functions

The number of roots of the equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^3}-3x+\sin x$ is 
$(A)0\hspace{1cm}(B)1\hspace{1cm}(C)2\hspace{1cm}(D)$more than 2

How can i find the number of zeroes of this function without using graphing calculator.There seems no method to predict the number of zeroes.Please guide me.

Comment: Try to examine the subexpression $(x+1)^{-3} - 3x$. When can it be in the interval $[-1, 1]$ (hint: there's two intervals of $x$ where this is possible)? How about it's slope there? Then compare with the range an slope of $-\sin x$ (the roots are where $(x+1)^{-3} - 3x = -\sin x$).

Comment: **Hint:** compute the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $-\infty$ , $-1^-$, $1^+$ and $+\infty$, and note that they are $+\infty$, $-\infty$, $+\infty$ and $+\infty$ respectively

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Those are $\pm\infty$, how are that going to help much? You need more than that to determine the answer.

Comment: @skyking at once you can see that at least it has two roots, with a little more thought you will see that they are only 2

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Yes, but the crusial part is to see it's behavior for values near zero. What it does with large values are of secondary interrest, if it weren't so that you knew that it were decreasing you would have no use for that observation (and especially you have no use of other of it's behaviour once it passed zero - ie the limits at infinity is of minor use).

Comment: @skyking please see the answer given by mathlove, it uses exactly my hint. When I told you a little more of thought I was thinking of seeing that $f'$ is always negative

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Yes, but that seem to focus more on the fact that $f'$ is negative (ie that $f$ is decreasing) - which should be the more central fact to figure out. The next is of course to analyze where it can change sign.

Comment: @skyking that was why I was only giving a HINT! Also as I told you with my hint it was enough to know that there were at least two roots, then one naturally come up with the derivative to see that there are in fact only two!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$f'(x)=-\frac{3}{(x+1)^4}-3+\cos x\le -\frac{3}{(x+1)^4}-3+1=-\frac{3}{(x+1)^4}-2\lt 0$$
So, $f(x)$ is decreasing. Also, we have
$$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x)=\mp\infty,\quad \lim_{x\to -1^{\pm}}f(x)=\pm\infty.$$

Thus, we know that the number of zeros is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to solve is first draw $h(x)=Sinx$

Next plot the curve

$$g(x)=3x-\frac{1}{(x+1)^3}$$ $x=-1$ is Asymptote of $g(x)$ So using

$$\lim_{x\to-1^-}g(x) \to +\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to-1^+}g(x) \to -\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x) \to -\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(x) \to +\infty$$ and finally $$g(0)=-1$$ you could easily observe that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ meet at two distinct points, Hence two Zeros